# C table indexes in preprocessor output

Tags: indexing, datatable, c-preprocessor

I use the following make command to obtain the preprocessor output (**AIX system**):

```
make USER_CFLAGS=-E source.o > output.txt
```

Is it possible to force preprocessor to calculate table index expressions to obtain, for example:

```
long_name[20];
```

instead of

```
long_name[19 + 1];
```

Comment: No, but could you please explain what the _actual_ problem is you wish to solve?

Comment: I need to parse preprocessor output file to generate some code automatically and I would like to ommit to caclulate such expressions myself. I already found a solution but it's time consument.

Answer (score 0):

This script uses perl (reads stdin writes stdout)

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

while (<>) {
    $_ =~ s/\[ *(\d+) *\+ *(\d+) *\]/ '['.($1+$2).']' /ge;
    print $_;
}
```

example input:

```
[ 10 + 200 ] , [ 11 + 48 ]
```

example output:

```
[210] , [59]
```

Comment: Thanks, but in the preprocessor output the expressions are generally freely complex  including any operators, brackets and sizeof(). ;)

Comment: Sorry that I cannot help :( Also I'm quite quite sure you have an XY-problem. http://xyproblem.info/